# How can I make my embedded svg image stetch to fill a container?

Tags: svg

I have an embedded svg that is will only stretch to about 2/3 of it's container size. I would like to get it to fill the entire container.

Here's how it currently looks:

[image]

I have a plunker here showing the embedded svg: http://plnkr.co/edit/5PbBmhV6aBiAtanXTVgM

The simplified svg structure is like this:

```
    <svg id="approach_shot" viewBox="0 0 360 360" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="content">
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" width="360" height="360"></rect>
        <g id="green">
          <defs>
            <circle id="ball" r="6" stroke="#000000" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="0.5"></circle>
          </defs>
          <g>
              <path fill="#005C1F" stroke="#005C1F" stroke-width="0.75" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M42.09 171.26c-10.48-25.3-9.77-52.43-0.17-75.92l-18.48-7.65c-11.56 28.22-12.42 60.83 0.17 91.23 0.08 0.2 0.17 0.4 0.25 0.6l18.48-7.65C42.26 171.65 42.17 171.46 42.09 171.26z"/>
              more paths...
          </g>
          <g id="shots">
            <use xlink:href="#ball" transform="translate(150,150) scale(1.0)" />
          </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

I've been hacking on this for a few hours, and nothing I do impacts that green image. The outer rectangle fills the container just fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to fix your `viewBox` attribute.  You currently have it set to a width and height of 360, when your circle is only about 247 in diameter.

The top-left of the circle is at roughly (11, 9.5), so changing your viewBox to:

```
viewBox="11 9.5 247 247"
```

will cause it to fill your viewport.

How did I determine the dimensions of the circle?  I used a little bit of javascript and called the `getBBox()` function on the element with id="green".

```
var b = document.getElementById("green").getBBox();
alert(b.x+" "+b.y+" "+b.width+" "+b.height);
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/j784zvLo/)

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you. It makes sense, sort of, but I have to admit my grasp of the viewBox attribute is fuzzy.

Comment: It's actually very simple.  All the viewBox does is describe the (rectangular) bounds of the area of your SVG that you want to be scaled to fit the viewport.  How exactly the scaling happens is determined by the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.