# Equivalent of "background-size: fill" for SVG <image> element

Tags: html, svg

I have a situation where I have a SVG graphic whose width is a percentage of the viewport, and whose height is fixed. Inside the graphic I have an [SVG `image` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image) which I want to always fill its immediate container without distorting, much as would be achieved by using CSS `background-size: fill`.

How can I achieve this using my SVG?

Here's a minimal setup of the problem ([and a codepen](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/jaZzdB?editors=1000)):

```html
<svg width=100% height=300>
  <rect width=100% height=300 stroke="blue" stroke-width=30 fill="transparent" />
  <image xlink:href="//unsplash.it/500/300" width=100% height=100% />
</svg>
```

In the above snippet, I need the image to fill the entire container without distorting (in this instance, the container being the root SVG), regardless of viewport width.

I can't switch to regular HTML because the graphic I'm working on has an SVG clipping mask applied to the `image` element.

I found this question, which seems close to what I'm asking, but I don't think answers my question:

[How can I make my embedded svg image stetch to fill a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101734/how-can-i-make-my-embedded-svg-image-stetch-to-fill-a-container)

In hopes of avoiding [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), here's [the actual SVG graphic I'm working on](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/gXvxYP). And the (fixed-height, variable-width) result I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the height of the image unchanged, set the fixed value of the viewport height and `preserveAspectRatio = "none"`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300" preserveAspectRatio = "none">
  <image width="500" height="300" xlink:href="//unsplash.it/500/300"/>
</svg>
```

**UPD**

The proportions of the picture will not change, the height remains fixed when using  `preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"`

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300" viewBox="0 0 500 300" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">

  <image width="100%" height="300" xlink:href="//unsplash.it/500/300" />
</svg>
```

**UPD2**

I looked [your codepen](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/gXvxYP) Like the idea. I've finished it with your permission. Modified some parameters

```html
<svg width="100%" height="400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
  <defs>
    <mask id="clipping">
      <rect width="100%" height="400" fill="white"/>
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="120%" rx="75%" ry="37%"/>
    </mask>
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="white"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="blue"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect   width="100%" height="400" fill="orange" mask="url(#clipping)" transform="translate(-20 12) rotate(-2.5)" />
  <image xlink:href="https://unsplash.it/1000/500" width="100%" height="400" mask="url(#clipping)" transform="translate(0 -10)" />
  <rect  width="100%" height="400" fill="url(#Gradient1)" mask="url(#clipping)" transform="translate(0 -10)" opacity="0.25" /> 
  
  </svg>
```

Comment: This is interesting, too, but the image is distorted.

Comment: Of course it is, you either preserve the aspect ratio or you distort the image. Pick which one you want.

Comment: @NathanArthur Added one more option. The picture is not distorted, the height is fixed

Comment: @RobertLongson And maybe I'm going about this whole thing wrong (see the end of my question for what I'm trying to achieve), but I'm asking specifically if the behavior of `background-image: fill` can be achieved within an SVG. Meaning--the image is not distorted, and neither does its container preserve its aspect ratio.

Comment: @Alexandr_T Thank you! I'll have to read up on the `preserveAspectRatio` attribute. It looks super useful.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, as I think it comes closest to what I was originally looking for.

Comment: @Nathan Arthur I was interested to look for a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Svg scaling with image

If you add a viewbox to the svg the svg knows how to scale.
Now adding the same viewBox ratio as the svg makes it so the svg will always have the same scale as the image.
You can always scale the image to its inside the viewBox.
Then it will always scale with the svg.

```css
svg {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
  <image width="500" height="300" xlink:href="//unsplash.it/500/300"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is nice, but I need to be able to constrain the height of the SVG, meaning the SVG will have a variable aspect ratio, so I can't encode it into the viewbox.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using two SVGs and an image which used a clipping mask defined in the first SVG to clip it down. I was able to make the SVGs scale by only defining a viewbox, not a width and height. I opted to use a fixed aspect ratio instead of a fixed height, percentage width, as I had originally planned.

```css
body > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  clip-path: url(#clipper);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="arch" viewBox="0 0 1000 400">
      <path d="M0 0 H 1000 V 400 Q 500 300, 0 400" />
    </symbol>
    
    <clipPath id="clipper" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0 0 H 1 V 1 Q .5 .75, 0 1" />
    </clipPath>
    
    <linearGradient id="Gradient1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#87AFBF"/>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#002855"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  
  <use href="#arch" width="100%" y="-40" fill="#F9B000" transform="translate(-20 12) rotate(-2.5)" />
</svg>

<img src="//unsplash.it/1000/400" alt="">

<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 500">
  <use href="#arch" y="-50" fill="url(#Gradient1)" opacity="0.75" />
</svg>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/narthur/pen/KyQxmQ?editors=1100)

Comment: Your decision is very solid and free from the shortcomings that I had (+)